# On the definition of Petri map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve (Over $\mathbb C$) and $A$ be a line bundle on it.Let's denote $K_C$ to be the canonical bundle on $C$. Then In many sources it's given that we have a map called "Petri" map given by the following:

$ H^0(A) \otimes H^0(K_C \otimes A^*) \to H^0(K_C)$.

It's also mentioned that It's a cup -product homomorphism  and it's basically given by multiplication of sections.

Now at this point my question is : I can understand that,considering $ \mathcal F = A$ and $ \mathcal G =  K_C \otimes A^*$, we have the obvious global section of the sheafification map $H^0(\mathcal F) \otimes H^0(\mathcal G) \to H^0( \mathcal F \otimes  \mathcal G)$. But I don't see how is it given by

$(1)$ product of sections ,$(2)$ how to interpret it as cup product?

Can somebody give me the explicit definition?(Or may be a source which discusses it explicitly?)

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: Never put comma after "let".

Comment: @Sasha,I have edited it.

Comment: For (1), it's a general fact that over any open set, a section $s$ of $\mathcal F$ and a section $t$ of $\mathcal G$ induce a section $st$ of $\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal G$, so in particular this produces a map of global sections. It's interesting to ask when this map is not surjective since, for instance, the map $H^0(\mathcal O(n))\otimes H^0(\mathcal O(m)) \to H^0(\mathcal O(n + m))$ associated to a pair of line bundles on $\mathbb P^n$ is always surjective.